# OIM - Provisioning an account on entitlement request

Tags: oim

Is it possible to provision an account on entitlement request or OIM expects an account to already exist before the entitlement request?

I already have an application instance, it has 2-3 entitlements

when an OIM user requests an entitlement to a specific application instance, I assume this OIM user must already have an account in the application instance

Comment: are you trying to provision through code or through UI? Also specify the version of OIM you are using in this scenario

Answer (score 3):

In the R2 version of OIM, once you add an entitlement from the Catalog it automatically adds the corresponding App Instance.

In case your application has an approval required the entitlement will not be provisioned and will be "In Progress" state. Once the request is approved, it will be provisioned.

Answer (score 2):

I believe version 11.1.2.2 and later will automatically include an account with the request if its not provisioned to the user when they request the entitlement connected to it.

Otherwise, in previous versions the account needed to be provisioned first before entitlements could be requested for users.

Answer (score 2):

In 11gR2PS2 and PS3(Before that it wasn't) its possible to raise request for entitlements even if dependent account did not provisioned. If tried to raise request for entitlement, dependent account would automatically added into the Cart.

If there is approval workflow for both entitlement as well as account and request of entitlement get approved first before of dependent account, entitlement remained **In Progress**. Once request for account approved & completed entitlements automatically moved to **Provisioned** from **In Progress**

Answer (score 1):

In OIM11g R2PS2 and PS3 ,while requesting for entitlement,if account is not already provisioned,than request for account will be added i.e account will be first provisioned and than entitlement will be granted.

Answer (score 0):

Till OIM 11GR2PS1 you need to request the account separately but starting PS2 Account gets provisioned automatically.